# Is a segmentation fault an effect of undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

A segmentation fault happens when you access memory that you're not supposed to. This can also be, for example, when you dereference an address outside of an array bound. The standard defines this as undefined behavior, so can a segmentation fault be what happens when undefined behavior occurs in that situation?

In other words, are segmentation faults the result of UB and are as variable as any other behavior that occurs when you perform a memory access violation?

Comment: Well, if undefined behaviour means anything can happen, then a segmentation fault is one of the things that can happen.

Comment: Wow, this is getting philosophical. Anyway, UB can be anything, but some can be considered "highly probable to result in a segmentation fault on platform X". Additionally, some platforms can provide an implementation-defined, *reliable* way of inducing a segfault (or its Windows equivalent, the Access Violation), in which case it would not be undefined behavior.

Comment: @Medinoc "undefined behaviour" means "undefined by the C++ standard" .

Comment: A segmentation fault *may* happen when you access memory that you're not supposed to.

Comment: Put it this way: the standard never says "this will cause a segmentation fault". So if you get a segmentation fault, it's either undefined behaviour or outside your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"are segmentation faults the result of UB". They're certainly **not** the result of defined behavior, or even unspecified behavior. I don't think they're ever implementation-defined behavior.

"are [they] as variable as any other behavior that occurs when you perform a memory access violation?

They're generally more predictable. Writing to memory which is allocated to your process can cause all kind of weird bugs. Segfaults happen when you write to other addresses, and the result is then always a segfault or bus error (a misaligned write outside your address space is still misaligned)

Comment: @Deduplicator that doesn't trigger a segfault, it triggers the signal handler fo a segfault etc.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: How would you distinguish that?

Comment: If you mean from within the signal handler - you can't. But that doesn't change the fact of whether a segmentation fault occurred

Comment: @Deduplicator: For instance, `raise(SIGSEGV)` works on Windows even though it doesn't have SegFaults but Access Violations. SegFault is a POSIX thing. Furthermore, a segfault sets `siginfo_t.si_addr`

Comment: @MSalters: Well, and Linux does not have a bluescreen, only a kernel panic. Using a different moniker does not change the thing described.