# Does the runtime dereference of a nullptr always result in Segmentation Fault?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, undefined-behavior, dereference, nullptr

##### tl;dr

What happens if ***"at runtime"*** a pointer `p` such that `p == nullptr` is dereferenced and its "pointee" is read from/written to?

Does that imply 100% a segmentation fault because the memory address 0 can't just be read from/written to?

---

The reason why I wrote ***"at runtime"***, is that I'm aware that the *compiler* will assume that `p != nullptr` when it sees `*p` (with `p` raw pointer), so some `*p` can just disappear due to UB, and effectively at runtime no `nullptr` is dereferenced at that point and the program keeps going though the alleys of undefined behavior.

For instance, given this TU,

```cpp
int* bar();

int foo(int* i) {
    return *i;
}

int work() {
    int* b = bar();
    int f = foo(b);
    return b != nullptr ? 0 : (f + *bar());
}
```

the compiler can assume `bar() =! nullptr` just by seeing that its return value is dereferenced by `foo`'s body, which can only be done if `bar() != nullptr`. Indeed the function `work` is compiled down to

```
work():
        sub     rsp, 8
        call    bar()
        xor     eax, eax
        add     rsp, 8
        ret
```

where the value returned by `bar()` is never actually derenferenced, even if `*bar()` is in the source code.

But `foo` (imagine it alone in its own TU, so there's no UB going on) is compiled down to

```
foo(int*):
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rdi]
        ret
```

so if this TU is linked against another one that calls `foo(nullptr)`, then the `mov` instruction will definitely try to read from the address in `rdi` which is whatever `nullptr` is compiled to, I guess 0.

Does that mean that Segmentation Fault is unavoidable? (I'm not saying I want to avoid segv, quite the opposite, I'm just wondering if things can go so wrong that there's no segv and the program keeps going who knows where!)

---

(¹) I'm aware that [the issue of whether dereferencing a null pointer is UB is still unresolved](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76902546/5825294), but this is not a duplicate of [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78043070/does-any-major-c-compiler-offer-a-flag-to-instrument-code-for-asserting-non-nu).

Comment: Undefined behavior means anything can happen including but not limited to your expected output. But never rely on the output of a program that has UB. The program "may" just crash.

Comment: [Consistency of undefined behavior for a fixed compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74155360/consistency-of-undefined-behavior-for-a-fixed-compiler) and [Why is the phrase: "undefined behavior means the compiler can do anything it wants" true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49032551/why-is-the-phrase-undefined-behavior-means-the-compiler-can-do-anything-it-wan)

Comment: [Is a segmentation fault an effect of undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26026940/is-a-segmentation-fault-an-effect-of-undefined-behavior) and [Is segmentation fault actual undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25636753/is-segmentation-fault-actual-undefined-behavior-when-we-refer-to-a-non-static-da)

Comment: *"Does the runtime dereference of a nullptr always result in Segmentation Fault?"* **No**, from the standard's perspective the behavior is undefined.

Comment: @user12002570, regarding the last comment, I'm not sure if I've stressed enough that I'm referring to something that happens _after_ the compiler has done its job and has gone home leaving two TUs behind that did not invoke UB.

Comment: If your program dereferences a null pointer a runtime, in Linux the zero page is intentionally left unmapped, so you will get a segfault there. [Unless you mapped some memory there yourself.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63790813/21105992) Which you can.

Comment: Some parts of the world still use MS-DOS which does not have segfaults and has valid memory around address zero. If you count this as a valid platform, the answer to the title is no.

Comment: A "segmentation fault" can only occur on platforms that have memory segmentation. So the answer is obviously no.

Comment: One possible manifestation of UB is compiler refusing to enter an `if` branch that contains UB, not checking the condition at all, and instead going to the `else` branch that doesn't have UB. Does this answer your question?

Comment: According to the standard:  there is no guarantee of anything.   Practically, there is no guarantee either.  On some (non-linux) unix systems, I have seen dereferences of null pointers result in a bus error instead of a segfault.    Once, on a non-unix and non-windows system, I saw a C developer accidentally clear, necessitating reformat, a hard drive by assigning a value to the result of multiple dereferencing (triple dereferencing I think) a null pointer  (he was very fortunate that it was a new hard drive, with no critical data to lose).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, isn't that essentially what I'm showing with the ternary operator and the text following that code snippet?

Comment: But if you know that, then I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing several concerns into one question here which amplifies the confusion in this matter. You should take care to distinguish:

- Your C++ program - Undefined behavior is undefined. Anything could happen. That is all that the standard says in this matter, and as your question is tagged C++, there is nothing more to say from a C++ perspective.
- The executed machine code - The compiler will most likely still produce *some* machine code for your attempted dereference operation. You won't be able to tell what machine code you will get beforehand, as the compiler can do whatever it wants due to the UB at play. But I understand your question in the way that you are observing the generated machine code *after* the translation: This machine code of course has well defined semantics in the context of the executing hardware platform and, potentially, influenced by the operating system it is run on. You can consult the documentation for both to find out what the exact behavior will be, and this will be the reliable outcome of the execution, regardless of what the C++ standard says. As you did not tag your target platform and OS in the question, I will refrain from guessing what will happen on your machine.

So in short: You won't know what happens by looking at the C++ code. You are, in principle, able to know what will happen when looking at the generated binary, given that you understand the behavior of your target platform well enough.

To answer the literal headline of your questions: there do exist hardware/OS configurations in the real world (in particular in embedded systems) where dereferencing the null address will not be caught by either the hardware or the OS, so you cannot rely on this always resulting in program termination by the environment.

In practice, should you care? Not unless you need to reason about the behavior of a pre-generated binary which you are unable to change. From a C++ perspective it is easy enough to perform a null check before dereferencing and (reliably) terminating the program manually if that is the desired outcome. Reasoning about program behavior *after* the actual dereferencing occurred is not sensible from a C++ perspective.

Answer (score 1):

**The short answer**: dereferencing `nullptr` is UB and does *not* always result into a segmentation fault.

That is because it depends on:

- what the compiler does,
- what the program does.

I've seen code like this in production code (simplified in this example, the lines were obviously not close to each other in the actual case):

```
struct SomeType;
void f(SomeType const& ref)
{
  if (&ref == nullptr)
    // bailout
  // ...
}
void g()
{
  SomeType* p = nullptr;
  f(*p);
}
```

Crazy, right?  But you can see why that "works", if you assume that references are implemented as pointers by the compiler...

But, as mentioned in many of the comments, you *should not* write code like that.  Although this is sometimes more easily said than done (we all write buggy code at some point...).

---

At the risk of going slightly off-topic, let me explain how the above issue was  identified in the said production code, because it eventually caused a segmentation fault.

The check on `nullptr` was not in the code of the function, it was instead in the logic of `dynamic_cast`, which results in `nullptr` when applied to `nullptr`.  Unfortunately, a new version of GCC came with an optimisation in `dynamic_cast` that removed the check on `nullptr` when the pointer was determined to not be nullable, as in the case of taking the address of a reference...

```
void f(SomeType const& ref)
{
  if (dynamic_cast<SomeOtherType const*>(&ref) == nullptr)
    // bailout
  // ...
}
```

In this instance, the issue was relatively quickly identified and the code fixed... but this is just one example among many!